# jquery post request not working getting 404 status

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, http-post

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://apius.faceplusplus.com/detection/detect',
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + Base64.encode('abc123' + ":" + 'xyz123')
              },
            data: dataURL,    //sending image 
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               alert(JSON.stringify(responseData));
            },
            error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(responseData));
            }
        });
```

dataURL is //Base064 Encode & compress below 20 kb
    var dataURL = compressImage(canvas, 20);
Basically I am sending image fro detection.
The error is:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(NOT FOUND)
I am getting status 404 in alert.
Please suggest any solution.

Comment: You made a `GET` request, not a `POST` request

Comment: sorry typo error..but same error in case of POST too.

Comment: dataUrl is var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', compression);

Comment: i would check your api key.

Comment: these are dummy keys I have checked that part is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good habit I found when dealing with ajax is **I always check the ajax url manually with my browser**, so if there is something wrong with it definitely my ajax wont work.

So I did same thing for you and I found this data:

```
{
    "error": "MISSING_ARGUMENTS: api_key", 
    "error_code": 1004
}
```

*So were you expecting to get this data on your success handler function?* That is not bad but it is not coming to the success function because the response status is set to error.

To check the error open the developer console( google chrome)  -> network -> headers, then look at the value of `status code` and you will get:

```
400 BAD REQUEST
```

So ***you are getting error 400 rather than 404***. And I hope you are getting this because you are not passing the api_key argument.

*update:*
I am not sure where the server is looking the keys from ( from headers vs params). But to send it using ajax as data param do this:

```
data:{ dataUrl: dataUrl, data api_key:"abc123",api_secret :"xyz123"}
```

Comment: can you please suggest me how should I send my authantication data api_key:abc123 and api_secret :xyz123 which I am sending in header in above code.